"Momentum" of spinning disc from collision -- conserving momentum of input momentum?
I have an application for which I have concluded a collision lets conserve momentum.
Examples of the type of scenario in which I believe my conclusion applies:

a waterwheel blade hit by a ball (wheel approximated by disc)
a tyre flying over ground hitting ground and starting to roll (tyre approximated by disc)

For my application (the tyre) a single (translational) input momentum results on collision in a spinning disc (I assume all input momentum is transferred to the disc making it spin and progress on the ground due to friction between them, no slip occurs).
I came up with this equation:
$$M_{input}v_{input} = \sum_{all\,items} m_{item}v_{item} \tag1\label{e1}$$
Therein "item" is an approximation of a particle having mass and all items make up the rigid body which is the spinning disc.
$v_{item}$ is the speed along the arc length when items are situated in rings in the disc.
$v_{input}$ is the translational speed before the collision.
$M_{input}$ and $m_{item}$ are mass.


Is $\eqref{e1}$ a correct assessment of my application?
Note:
I'm aware of "angular momentum" as defined in literature as $\vec{L} = \vec{r}\times\vec{p}$ (and its sum for derivation of that for rotating rigid bodies). If this is to be used on the right hand side of $\eqref{e1}$ instead, I would like to know the reason for this, in particular the reason for the extra $\vec{r}\times$.

Hi. Please [edit] your question and add only the relevant details to what you want to ask, and do not post images of equations but use math formatting instead. Look into the help for math notation.

Hi @JohnAlexiou. I edited my question and hopefully made more clear what I'm asking. I moved the calculation of the end result as given in the 2 images deleted to link and link

I found link. Total linear momentum, total angular momentum and total energy, total as before plus after collision, is each independantly from each other preserved in a collision when no forces act on the participants from outside, angular momentum with regards to 1 origin (for $\vec{r}$). This is a starting point. The question from my note is obsolete, the units don't match anyway. I'm still intrigued whether the tyre spin can be derived like I did from a microscopic perspective rather than from the holistic look in the intro of this comment

wrt preservation in a collision: total x = collider's x + obstacle's x before collision = collider's x + obstacle's x after collision; not: total x = collider's x before collision + collider's x after collision.

Origin at center of mass
For a single particle, angular momentum is defined similarly to torque, as the moment-of-momentum, just as torque is moment-of-force. Both correspond to a measurement of something done with respect to the origin.
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Quantity} & \text{Definition} \\
\hline
\text{torque}  & \boldsymbol{\tau} = \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{F} \\
\text{ang. momentum}  & \boldsymbol{L} = \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{p} \\
\end{array}$$
where $\boldsymbol{r}$ is the position vector of the thing measured relative to the origin, $\boldsymbol{F}$ is a force applied somewhere, and $\boldsymbol{p}$ is the (translational) momentum of a particle.
In a similar fashion to considering the torque as a result of a distributed force as
$$ \boldsymbol{\tau}_{\rm net} = \sum_{i} \boldsymbol{r}_i \times \boldsymbol{F}_i \tag{1}$$
angular momentum also can be summed up when dealing with a collection of particles
$$ \boldsymbol{L}_{\rm net} = \sum_{i} \boldsymbol{r}_i \times \boldsymbol{p}_i = \sum_i \boldsymbol{r}_i \times (m_i \boldsymbol{v}_i) \tag{2}$$
where $m_i$ is the mass of the particle and $\boldsymbol{v}_i$ is the (translational) velocity of the particle.
Now consider the kinematics of a general rotating rigid body consisting of multiple particles fixed with each other.

The velocity of each particle can be expressed as
$$\boldsymbol{v}_i = \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{r}_i \tag{3}$$
which makes the summing of angular momentum be
$$\boldsymbol{L}_{\rm COM} = \sum_i \boldsymbol{r}_i \times m_i ( \boldsymbol{\omega}\times \boldsymbol{r}_i ) \tag{4}$$
Here the vector triple product identity $a\times(b\times c) = b (a\cdot c) - c (a\cdot b)$ is used to factor out the common term $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ since it is shared among all particles.
$$\boldsymbol{L}_{{\rm COM}}=\left[\sum_{i}m_{i}\left(\left(\boldsymbol{r}_{i}\cdot\boldsymbol{r}_{i}\right){\bf 1}-\left(\boldsymbol{r}_{i}\odot\boldsymbol{r}_{i}\right)\right)\right]\boldsymbol{\omega} \tag{5}$$
where $\bf 1$ is the identity matrix, and $\odot$ the outer product operator
Commonly the big sum is pre-evaluated since it depends on the geometry only and not on the operational circumstances of the problem. This gives rise to the definition of the mass moment of inertia tensor.
$$ {\rm I}_{{\rm COM}}=\sum_{i}m_{i}\left(\left(\boldsymbol{r}_{i}\cdot\boldsymbol{r}_{i}\right){\bf 1}-\left(\boldsymbol{r}_{i}\odot\boldsymbol{r}_{i}\right)\right) \tag{6}$$
which is applied as
$$\boldsymbol{L}_{{\rm COM}}={\rm I}_{{\rm COM}}\boldsymbol{\omega} \tag{7}$$
Origin at an arbitrary place
When doing the above sum, but about an origin not at the center of mass, then there is an additional term that comes out, relating to the total (translational) momentum
$$\boldsymbol{p} = \sum_i m_i \boldsymbol{v}_i = {\rm M}\, \boldsymbol{v}_{\rm COM} \tag{8} $$
when going step by step you find that angular momentum summed about the origin (at the arbitrary point A) is
$$\boldsymbol{L}_{A}={\rm I}_{{\rm COM}}\boldsymbol{\omega}+\boldsymbol{r}_{{\rm COM}}\times\boldsymbol{p} \tag{9}$$
It is worth going through this derivation on your own in order to really understand it on your own terms.
